# Powershell Create User Script not resolving

Tags: powershell

So my php issue resolved I went on to my powershell script to create users based off the CSV that is generated from the php process. However when I run the script the users aren't created and there is no error log being created to show me why. (Although this is because I think I am missing something within script for proper logging of errors.) I have used a version of this script before when I first created all the users on this DC. So I can't really tell why this is doing this. So once again figured I'd post my code and see if maybe someone could pinpoint what the problem might be. Sorry to be a bother. Just seems like this would be the best place to ask.

```
Try
{
    Import-Module ActiveDirectory -ErrorAction Stop
}
Catch
{
    Write-Host "[ERROR]`t ActiveDirectory couldn't be loaded. Script will stop." 
    Exit 0
}
$path = "\\NetworkShare\Csvfile"
$date = Get-Date
$addn = (Get-ADDomain).DistuinguishedName
$dnsroot = (Get-ADDomain).dnsroot
$i = 1
$log = "\\NetworkShare\Csvfile.log"
$enabled = $True
Function Start-Commands
{
    Create-Users
}
Function Create-Users
{
    "Processing started (on " + $date + "): " | Out-File $log -append
    "--------------------------------------------" | Out-File $log -append
    Import-CSV $path | ForEach-Object {
        If (($_.FirstName -eq "") -Or- ($_.LastName -eq ""))
        {
            Write-Host "[ERROR]`t No FirstName or LastName provided. Processing skipped for line $($i)`r`n"
            "[ERROR]`t Please provide valid GivenName, LastName and Initials. Processing skipped for line $($i)`r`n" | Out-File $log -append
        }
        Else
        {
           #Set Target OU
           $location = $_.Department + ".$($addn)"
           #Replace dots in names to avoid errors
           $replace = $_.Lastname.Replace(".","")
           #Create Account using name convention of First Initial and Last name
           $sam = $_.FirstName.substring(0,1).ToLower() + $_.LastName.ToLower()
           Try { $exists = Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(sAMAccountName=$sam)" }
           Catch { }
           If (!$exists)
           {
            #Set variables according to CSV headers. If headers differ change variables below as well
            $setpass = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $_.Password -force
            }
            Try
            {
                Write-Host "[INFO]`t Creating user : $($sam)"
                "[INFO]`t Creating user : $($sam)" | Out-File $log -append
                New-ADUser $sam -GivenName $_.FirstName -Initials $_.Initials `
                -Surname $_.LastName -DisplayName ($_.LastName + "," + $_.FirstName) `
                -UserPrincipalName ($sam + "@" + $dnsroot) -OfficePhone $_.Number `
                -AccoutPassword $setpass -Enabled $enabled
                Write-Host "[INFO]`t Created new user : $($sam)"
                "[INFO]`t Created new user : $($sam)" | Out-File $log -append

                $dn = (Get-ADUser $sam).DistuinguishedName
                 #Move to OU set above
                 If ([adsi]::Exists("LDAP://$($location)"))
                {
                    Move-ADObject -Identity $dn -TargetPath $location
                    Write-Host "[INFO]`t User $sam moved to target OU : $($location)"
                    "[INFO]`t User $sam moved to targ OU : $($location)" | Out-File $log -append
                }
                Else 
                {
                    Write-Host "[ERROR]`t Target OU not found. User Wasn't Moved!"
                    "[ERROR]`t Target OU not found. User wasn't moved!" | Out-File $log -append
                }
                #Object Renamed
                $newdn = (Get-ADUser $sam).DistuinguishedName
                Rename-ADObject -Identity $newdn -NewName ($_.FirstName + " " + $_.LastName)
                Write-Host "[INFO]`t Renamed $($sam) to $($_.GivenName) $($_.LastName)`r`n"
                 "[INFO]`t Renamed $($sam) to $($_.GivenName) $($_.LastName)`r`n" | Out-File $log -append
            }
            Catch
             {
                Write-Host "[ERROR]`t Oops. An error has occured: $($_.Exception.Message)`r`n"
             }
           Else
            {
          Write-Host "[SKIP]`t User $($sam) ($($_.FirstName) $($_.LastName)) already exists or returned an error!`r`n"
          "[SKIP]`t User $($sam) ($($_.FirstName) $($_.LastName)) already exists or returned an error!" | Out-File $log -append

            }
        }
      $i++ 
      "--------------------------------------------" + "`r`n" | Out-File $log -append 
    } 
}

Write-Host "STARTED SCRIPT`r`n"
Start-Commands
Write-Host "STOPPED SCRIPT`r`n"
```

Comment: If you load the script up into the ISE and step through it, can you find where it fails? Does it find the CSV file? Is there any output at all? Does it appear to create users (according to the Write-Host message if nothing else), but actually do nothing?

Comment: Running through ISE I can't find any errors. It seems to resolve. However my Write-Host doesn't go through so I'm not sure if I messed something up there so it isn't doing the Write-Host or if the I didn't but something is goofy with my script and the user creation is not going through but appearing as if it does. I also am pretty sure I have another error because when I run the script it pops up a message saying 'Supply values for the following parameters Process [0]." I know it means I missed something but I can't tell what.

Comment: Ok. So I edited the code to correct one of the multiple errors I found. The issue is the script now returns access denied. Is there a command I or a line I can add that will avoid an access is denied error? And what would I add at the end to delete the csv file after trhe script has run?

Comment: What specifically is giving you the access denied error? You can do `Remove-Item $path` to delete the CSV file. You may need to use the -force switch if it gives you issues trying to delete.

Comment: So I've found the error. Had to do with user permissions. Planning on creating a hidden operator AD account to account for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you've improperly wrapped your **If (!$exists)** code.  According to my editor, this is the entirety of that If statement:

```
If (!$exists)
           {
            #Set variables according to CSV headers. If headers differ change variables below as well
            $setpass = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $_.Password -force
            }
```

If I'm not mistaken, you want that to contain all the code down to the Else clause later.

Try moving the end brace **}** from line 46 to right before the **Else** on line 81.

Comment: Ok. I'll give that a shot.

Comment: While that did need to be corrected I still can't get it to resolve. And I'm not sure what is causing the issue. It's not creating the log either so I can't tell where maybe the hangup is. Nor is it running the write-host.